# Connecting to SQL Azure with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net, azure-sql-database

Hi I try to connect to a SQL AZURE DB with ADO.NET.

Here is my code:

```
private static string userName = "<**@********>";
private static string password = "<********>";
private static string dataSource = "<******.database.windows.net>";
private static string databaseName = "<******>";

public void Save()
{
    SqlDataReader queryResultCloud;
    string queryString = "select * from tblScan";


    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connString2Builder;
    connString2Builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connString2Builder.DataSource = dataSource;
    connString2Builder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
    connString2Builder.Encrypt = true;
    connString2Builder.TrustServerCertificate = false;
    connString2Builder.UserID = userName;
    connString2Builder.Password = password;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString2Builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString);
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        queryResultCloud = command.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

and I get next error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Comment: Do you have your IP address added to the firewall rules in azure?

Comment: Can you try connecting via Sql Server Management Studio using the same credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. One thing to try is to set TrustServerCertificate to true, and see if it works. Note it is recommended to set this property to false when Encrypt is set to true. But there’re reports that combination cause connection issues. I would like to suggest you to check http://www.wadewegner.com/2010/08/using-the-trustservercertificate-property-with-sql-azure-and-entity-framework/ for more information. In addition, check again if you have configured SQL Azure firewall to allow connection to your local machine. If you’re behind a proxy, it is needed to add your proxy’s IP address to the firewall exception.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely behind a proxy that doesn't allow outbound connections to port 1433, which is the only [port you can use with SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336282.aspx):

> The Windows Azure SQL Database service is only available with TCP port
>   1433. To access a SQL Database database from your computer, ensure that your firewall allows outgoing TCP communication on TCP port 1433.

I'm in this situation as well, and the most promising / challenging solution appears to be this [port bridging application technique](http://www.dotnetsolutions.co.uk/blog/connecting-to-sql-azure-without-changing-your-firewall), but the solution itself is dated and needs an older version of VS than I have installed, so I'm looking at some other alternatives.